# Apache Ignite SQLClient Connection from outside cluster

Tags: ignite

Apache Ignite is running in the 5 node hadoop cluster. Ignite Visor top command shows all the recognized nodes accurately. Outside the cluster, only one node is exposed as an edge node, using external ip.  I am unable to connect to the Apache Ignite Cluster from outside the cluster using the exposed ip of the edge node.

Working within cluster : jdbc:ignite:thin://127.0.0.1/
Working within cluster : jdbc:ignite:thin://internal-ip.labs.net/
Not Working Outside cluster : jdbc:ignite:thin://external-ip.labs.net/

Please advise if any additional configuration is needed in the edge node to make the jdbc url work using the external ip address also. I am trying to do this in order to connect to the ignite cluster from outside using a sql client so that I can run all the sqls.

**My Current Config**

```
    <bean id="grid.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
    <property name="discoverySpi">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
              <property name="ipFinder">
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.sharedfs.TcpDiscoverySharedFsIpFinder">
                      <property name="path" value="/storage/softwares/ignite/addresses"/>
                    </bean>
              </property>
            </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Did you expose port 10800 on the external IP? Are you able to connect to it using telnet?

Answer (score 1):

[Apache Ignite JDBC driver](https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/jdbc-driver) operates over port 10800 by default. You need to forward it from external IP to your Ignite node to be able to connect to the cluster using JDBC.